# get name of property or field in object typed

Tags: typescript

I have a injectable angular class with a readonly property. So I don't control the initialisation of this class. The class is supposed to be used in a library. Consumers of this library can access those properties but they are not allowed to modify thse.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyState {
   readonly requestToken: string;
}
```

The library writes the property through a trick.

```
self.state[<any>"requestToken"] = requestToken;
```

The problem is that if the name of the property changes the ts compilation will not detect the string assigment.

Is there a way to get the name of the property in a typed fashion.
Something like for example:

```
var nameOfRequestTokenProperty = somethingXxx MyState => requestToken;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the name of a property from the compiler, you can however make sure that if the name changes you will get an error, by using `keyof`:

```
const requestTokenName: keyof MyState = "requestToken"; // if requestToken is renamed it will cause an error here.
self.state[<any>requestTokenName] = requestToken;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but where is requestTokenName used and where does key come from?

Comment: @stephan.peters Wops, sorry, I initially used `key` and then renamed it but didn't do so everywhere, edited